# Would anyone know how to fix this conflicting types error im having on GCC while trying to use <graphics.h> on linux?

Tags: c, bgi

I keep getting this error as i try to run my program colour.c whilst using <graphics.h>,
the error is:

```
 In file included from colour.c:3:
/usr/include/curses.h:911:28: error: conflicting types for ‘getmaxx’
  911 | extern NCURSES_EXPORT(int) getmaxx (const WINDOW *);   /* generated */
      |                            ^~~~~~~
In file included from colour.c:2:
/usr/local/include/graphics.h:70:6: note: previous declaration of ‘getmaxx’ was here
   70 | int  getmaxx(void);
      |      ^~~~~~~
In file included from colour.c:3:
/usr/include/curses.h:912:28: error: conflicting types for ‘getmaxy’
  912 | extern NCURSES_EXPORT(int) getmaxy (const WINDOW *);   /* generated */
```

My program is short and simple, and just experimenting with graphics.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
  int gd = DETECT, gm;
  initgraph(&gd, &gm, NULL); /*  Change this to the path of your compiler  */

  setcolor(BLUE);
  rectangle(50,50,100,100);

  getch();
  closegraph();
  return 0; 
}
```

I'm using <curses.h> because I learned it was the Linux alternative to <conio.h>. is there any C programming wizard who can help me out?

Comment: If you are using curses, you probably shouldn't be using the graphics header too.  And vice versa.  Choose one, not both.